# Preventing Python requests.post to encode strings to UTF-8

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I am making an API call to an appliance, passing a message in a JSON payload via HTTP POST.

Despite not doing any character encoding, the string received is encoded in UTF-8.

Unfortunately, the appliance manufacturer requires no encoding for the message, and characters with accents are turned into 5-character codes :(

Here is the code:

```
import requests

payload = {
           "type": "send-message",
           "username": "myuser",
           "password": "mypass",
           "to": "456",
           "msg": "here are accents: é ç"
          }

resp = requests.post("http://192.168.1.10/send_message.html",json=payload)
```

The result seen by the recipient doesn't show the accent characters correctly:

[received message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3cHl.png)

Doing a tcpdump, I can see the HTTP POST made by requests.post contains the following payload:

```
{"type": "send-message", "username": "myuser", "password": "mypass", "to": "456", "msg": "here are accents: \u00e9 \u00e7"}
```

As you can see, the text has been encoded to UTF-8, which is not asked for anywhere in the code.

If I try to force decode  `"here are accents: é ç".decode('utf-8')` I get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` which makes sense because it's not encoded.

If I attempt to force ASCII: `"here are accents: é ç".encode('ascii','ignore')` then the accents will be lost.

Testing **with CURL it works perfectly**:

`curl -X POST 'http://192.168.1.10/send_message.html' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"type": "send-message","username": "myuser","password": "mypass","to": "456","msg": "here are accents: é ç" }'`

Looking at the tcpdump with the curl attempt from the linux CLI shows the JSON exactly as sent, and the appliance recognizes the accents and sends them exactly as expected.

Imported into Wireshark, the string sent by CURL which is not UTF-8 formatted, and is correctly interpreted looks like this:

[wireshark-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOcXq.png)

Is there a way to tell Python's requests.post NOT to translate to UTF-8, or do I have to re-code the HTTP POST?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Well, you have to convert your string to a bytesequence **somehow**. Which encoding would you like?

Comment: Python strings are UTF8 by default.

Comment: @MattDMo Strings are strings. The internal representation is simply irrelevant in this case.

Comment: What you are seeing in `tcpdump` output is ***not*** the result of UTF-8 encoding. Instead, it is a result of *unicode escaping* that turns the characters into ASCII-safe data. Any properly functional JSON parser will be able to deal with the result transparently. We are not tech support; please contact your appliance manufacturer for details on what data can actually be handled. Perhaps it does not support non-ASCII characters at all. If it expects you to handle those characters by sending ISO-8859-1 encoded text *within JSON serialized data*, it is not standards-compliant.

Comment: Dear All: thanks for your comments. As you can see it works great if using **curl** from the command line. So I am guessing we need to ask Python to send standard ascii. How can I create such a string that won't be re-converted by Python?

Comment: é and ç don't exist in ASCII. Again: Which encoding do you want?

Comment: Asked a different way: Which **bytes** do you see in tcpdump, when you test with curl?

Comment: "Looking at the tcpdump with the curl attempt from the linux CLI shows the JSON exactly as sent" You're looking at a string representation, not at the actual bytes sent over the wire.

Comment: Also: the `tcpdump` output shows you that the accented characters are translated into **six** bytes, not five. The data that was received from the internet connection actually contains a byte with value 0x5c = 92, and thus `tcpdump` translates it into an actual backslash.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel counting is hard :)

Comment: `curl -d` is intended for emulating url-encoded form data, not JSON either as a string or as raw binary. Not to mention the question of how *your terminal translates* command-line text into bytes. It seems like you are generally confused about *how text and data work in general*, on a level that makes it hard to extract a coherent question here. But start by explaining: **what happens** when you try using your code as is with the actual appliance, and **how is that different** from what you expect? For example, do you see wrong text on an LCD display?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your comments. Sören: I added the Wireshark capture. Karl: I added the result seen by the recipient. The ASCII table shows that these two letters with accents are on the extended ASCII table with decimal values 130 and 135, so we should be able to do without UTF-8?

Comment: The wireshark data shows the data *is* encoded in UTF-8.  The bytes `C3 A9` are UTF-8 encoding for `é`. but perhaps the API isn't JSON-standard compliant, where it *should* decode \u escape codes correctly but doesn't.

Comment: Suggest OP read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for some reason the target API is not fully JSON-compliant, you can build a JSON response manually and encode it in whatever encoding you like.  `ensure_ascii=False` wil disable non-ASCII translation to escape codes, and you can specify the encoding if it is non-standard.  The wireshark screenshot shows the data is actually UTF-8-encoded, so that is what I've done below:

```py
import requests
import json

payload = {
           "type": "send-message",
           "username": "myuser",
           "password": "mypass",
           "to": "456",
           "msg": "here are accents: é ç"
          }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps(payload, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
resp = requests.post("http://192.168.1.10/send_message.html", data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Hello Mark. Works great from first attempt! Thank you so much for your help, and for the recommended reading. I'll get on it right away. You rock! :)

Comment: I have spent hours solving this, using answers with more than 1k likes. This one is first that works. Others often suggest using .decode() after .encode('utf8') which didn't work for me. Good job.