# python post request arabic language issue utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, post, utf-8, request

I am sending dictionary in parameters through post request in python.
The issue is one of my key has value in Arabic language.The reciever is saying they are receiving data in that key as `"\u062c\u0648\u062c\u0644"`, I guess this is in utf-8 encoded form.

I just want to send my data in Arabic language.There is nothing that can be done from receiving side. So the code has to be done on my side.

The data i am sending.
`{'Data': {'SickLeaveDate': '1444-10-07', 'PatientEmployeer': 'جوجل', 'PatientJob': 'تطوير البرمجيات'}}`

The data they are receiving.
`{"Data": {"SickLeaveDate": "1444-10-07", "PatientEmployeer": "\u062c\u0648\u062c\u0644", "PatientJob": "\u062a\u0637\u0648\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0645\u062c\u064a\u0627\u062a"}}`

```
headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'apikey': XXXXXXXXX
        }

requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=dict)
```

Comment: It’s JSON encoding. If the receiver JSON-decodes that properly, they’ll get Arabic from it just fine.

Comment: As an aside, the `request` project specifically do not support this (see [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4580)), you will have to encode the payload using `json.dumps` with the `ensure_ascii=False` and submit the result using `data` field instead of `json` (and keep the `accept` header as you already have).

Comment: but the receiver is just connected to me through my client, I don't know which language is receiver using, they just say that they are getting this result they want it in Arabic.

Comment: Please do reference [the answer in the linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73129986/) for a more clear example on what you might need to do.

Comment: @metatoaster b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html dir="rtl">\r\n <head>\r\n <title>The given key was not present in the dictionary. returns something like this

Comment: We can’t tell you why that is. The JSON you’re sending is as correct as it can be, for all we can tell.

Answer (score 0):

That's a valid JSON string.  The receiver needs to decode JSON.  It's not "utf-8 encoded form".  It's escape codes for Unicode code points that in this case represent your Arabic characters.

```py
>>> import json
>>> s = '''{"Data": {"SickLeaveDate": "1444-10-07", "PatientEmployeer": "\u062c\u0648\u062c\u0644", "PatientJob": "\u062a\u0637\u0648\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0645\u062c\u064a\u0627\u062a"}}'''
>>> json.loads(s)
{'Data': {'SickLeaveDate': '1444-10-07', 'PatientEmployeer': 'جوجل', 'PatientJob': 'تطوير البرمجيات'}}
```

Comment: Yes while OP might be unaware, unfortunately this answer misses the fact that the ascii-based unicode escape results in significantly more bytes (nearly twice) being sent, and that the issue lies with the `request` library unable to do this, and in fact [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129491/preventing-python-requests-post-to-encode-strings-to-utf-8) (also, you have answered, I just realized).